Creating default object from empty value in YII2
Code that causes problem
foreach ($items as $itemData) {
     $item = new PurchaseItem();
     $item->internal_product_id = (int)$itemData['internal_product_id'];
     $item->quantity = (float)$itemData['quantity'];
     $item->total = (float)$itemData['total'];
     $item->purchase_id = $purchase->id;
     if (!$item->save()) {
        throw new \Exception('Error saving the purchase item.');
      }
}

Table Structure
CREATE TABLE `purchase_items` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `purchase_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_product_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL
)

I've tried to change the variable name for unique. also ensure the field name . But Results are same & not saving data in Purchase_items table

You can track the reason of not being saved by changing to throw new \Exception('Error saving the purchase item - reason: '.print_r( $item->getErrors(), 1 ) );. Active record will always contain the reason why not being saved.

Here is the problem i got on the code. In modal all the field was declare in public property that's why getting the error. after remove them it works fine.
class CompraItem extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $internal_product_id;
    public $purchase_id;
    public $quantity;
    public $total;
}


Is exampled structure of table final/full?
One of possible problem is absent of AUTO_INCREMENT for PRIMARY KEY (id).
Please, change structure of table to
CREATE TABLE `purchase_items` (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `purchase_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_product_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `total` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY (purchase_id),
  KEY (internal_product_id)
);

